# Put "plus" picture near menu item

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

How to put "plus" picture near menu item ? Here is the [link](http://45.55.85.113/products.html)

[image]

Comment: post the actual markup

Answer (score 1):

move the `<span class="collapse">` within the `<a>` tag

then to prevent the link from firing, within the function for collapse simply put

`e.preventDefault;` or `return false;`

Comment: hi, thanks for answer. in this case if i will press a plus the link will be pressed too and redirect will happen

Comment: take a look at my edit

Comment: your function should have (e) or (event) as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about their distance? look if the elements have width, if yes try to reduce it use display:inline-block, and changing width to min-width.you can wrap the text in a span and add little right margin if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your elements with class `expand` and `collapse` have an absolute positionning with `top: 0; right: 0;` That means its distance from the top and right edges (from its parent element) are 0 pixels.

What I would personally do in this case (not at all what would be recommended by CSS experts) would be removing the `right` rule from the class and add an inline `style="left: ##px"`inside each span.

On my screen, what works best is this combination :

```
<li class=" level0 nav-2 active level-top m-dropdown menu-style-dropdown parent">
    <a href="http://45.55.85.113/products.html" class="level-top">
        <span> <span class="category_icon fa fa-tags"></span>SHOP</span>
    </a><span class="expand" style="left: 55px"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></span>
    <ul class="level0" style="display: block;">
        <li class=" level1 item classic nav-2-1 first parent">
            <a href="http://45.55.85.113/products/furniture.html">
                <span> <span class="category_icon fa fa-key"></span>Furniture</span>
            </a><span class="collapse" style="left: 100px"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
            <ul class="level1">
                <li class=" level2 nav-2-1-1 first">
                    <a href="http://45.55.85.113/products/furniture/patio-furniture.html">
                        <span>Patio Furniture</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" level2 nav-2-1-2">
                    <a href="http://45.55.85.113/products/furniture/cafe-chairs-and-barstools.html">
                        <span>Cafe Chairs and Barstools</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" level2 nav-2-1-3 last">
                    <a href="http://45.55.85.113/products/furniture/chairs-seating.html">
                        <span>Chairs &amp; Seating</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class=" level1 item classic nav-2-2 parent">
            <a href="http://45.55.85.113/products/furniture-fixings.html">
                <span>Furniture Fixings</span>
            </a><span class="collapse" style="left: 135px"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
            <ul class="level1">
                <li class=" level2 nav-2-2-4 first">
                    <a href="http://45.55.85.113/products/furniture-fixings/connectors.html">
                        <span>Connectors</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" level2 nav-2-2-5 last">
                    <a href="http://45.55.85.113/products/furniture-fixings/insert-nuts.html">
                        <span>Insert Nuts</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class=" level1 item classic nav-2-3 last">
            <a href="http://45.55.85.113/products/electrical.html">
                <span>ELECTRICAL</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

or for short :

```
left: 55px;
left: 100px;
left: 135px;
```

respectively for Shop, Furniture and Furniture Fixing